# Find number of channels of PNG image with php

Tags: php, png, gd, imagick

How do I find the number of channels of an PNG image with php?

According to the documentation of getimagesize (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) it seems like this function always  will return the number of channels.

As far as I can see this is not the case.
Here is an example:

channel_test.php:

```
<?php
$path1 = "test.jpg";
$path2 = "homer.gif";
$path3 = "bmp_24.bmp";
$path4 = "tux.png";

$info1 = getimagesize($path1);
$info2 = getimagesize($path2);
$info3 = getimagesize($path3);
$info4 = getimagesize($path4);

echo "\nJPG:";
print_r($info1);

echo "\nGIF:";
print_r($info2);

echo "\nBMP:";
print_r($info3);

echo "\nPNG:";
print_r($info4);
?>
```

Output of channel_test.php:

```
JPG:Array
(
    [0] => 463
    [1] => 399
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="463" height="399"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)

GIF:Array
(
    [0] => 320
    [1] => 320
    [2] => 1
    [3] => width="320" height="320"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/gif
)

BMP:Array
(
    [0] => 200
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 6
    [3] => width="200" height="200"
    [bits] => 24
    [mime] => image/x-ms-bmp
)

PNG:Array
(
    [0] => 400
    [1] => 479
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="400" height="479"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
```

As you can see the number of channels is not returned for the BMP and PNG image.
Is this a bug or expected behavior? 
If it's expected I think the php documentation is a bit misleading.

Is there another way to get the number of channels?

I'm running php 5.4.9 (linux), both gd and imagick installed.

Comment: Code: https://github.com/ktomk/Miscellaneous/blob/master/get_png_imageinfo/get_png_imageinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an omission. The code just isn't there.

Comment: I reported this as a bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65749

At least the documentation was changed from "Returns an array with 7 elements." to "Returns an array with up to 7 elements. Not all image types will include the channels and bits elements."...